# smtp does not respond for yahoo and live (works with gmail)

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I wish to send mail via python script.

When using gmail credentials. the code works perfectly, but when using yahoo or live.com credentials, either i get connection refused or timeout error

```
import smtplib
client = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.mail.yahoo.com',port=465, timeout=100)
```

I get

```
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have already tried with port 587, 995, 25. Unfortunately it does not work

please help

Comment: Maybe your server is blacklisted?

Comment: @Cemal I also tried using different (cloud) machines. Unfortunately I am getting same error

Comment: Hey @maswadkar , just making sure you are doing `@yahoo.com`, right. Also, try making a SMTP connection with pure sockets.

Comment: @Cemal, you were right... when I used my non-cloud machine (raspberry pi 3)
it worked 
Thanks